# Repeating ScrollView content in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, scrollview

Is there a simple way to make a `ScrollView` repeat itself endlessly, i.e. just loop back to the beginning?

I have a `ScrollView` with 5 items, I just want to continually go over those 5 items again and again while scrolling, until the user selects one and moves on.

Comment: The trick is using a lazy list that repeats your items thousand times. User will have no motivation to scroll to the end.